# Spacing between tics in Gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I've been going crazy looking for an answer to this question. How can I set the distance between the tics on gnuplot? Currently the tics in my plot are squished together too tightly. I want them to be more spread out.

Here is an example:

I have a graph that looks like this:

```
100 ——
      |
      |
 50 —— 
      |
      |
  0 ——
```

I want it to look like this:

```
 50 ——
      |
      |
      | 
      |
      |
  0 ——
```

Notice that there is actually one less tic in the after sample.

Comment: Do you not perhaps want the upper label in the second example to be `100` rather than `50`? Or do you really want to zoom into the actual graph?

Answer (score 8):

The distance between tics is set by `set xtics` or `set ytics` command. For example if I use the command `plot sin(x)`
then the space between the `xtics` is 5 by default. The command

```
  set xtics  -10,2,10
  replot
```

makes the `xtics` appear at an interval of 2. In the above command the format is

```
  set xtics <start>, <increment>, <end>
```

See `help xtics` inside `gnuplot` for details.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have seen this answer else where but this is not what I'm asking. I want to actually increase the distance between the tics, not the interval they cover.

Comment: I have added an example for clarification.

Comment: Hi @KG, why, it is obvious that you will have to plot the same function (or data) with a shorter x and y ranges for increasing spaces between the ticks and then specifying the interval you would like the tics to be.

Answer (score 3):

As suggested in another answer by andyras ([Change actual space between tics in gnu plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25090698/change-actual-space-between-tics-in-gnu-plot)) you can do it by controlling the size of your terminal.
I also had a problem, where I wanted the tics in the axis to have the same distance in absolute values (though I don't know the value itselft, but the grid should be quadratic in the end).

So if you want a quadratic grid/spacing of your tics, put

```
set terminal pdfcairo size 100, 100
```

For rectangular put

```
set terminal pdfcairo 100, 200
```

and so on. 
Again, this is an answer suggested by andyras, not me. I took his answer, which worked for my case.