# Change actual space between tics in gnu plot

Tags: gnuplot

Example x-axis:

Before:

```
|____|____|____|
10  20   30   40
```

After:

```
|______________|______________|______________|
10            20             30             40
```

I have been searching for a while and have only found out how to scale everything else except the size between tics as simply as possible.

I don't desire to change the canvas size, the terminal size, the tic size, the number of tics etc... I want to stretch the x axis out. I don't care how big it makes the window.

Comment: Which terminal are you using? Generally you want to use the `size` parameter to the `set terminal` command to stretch everything out in one direction.

Comment: Try something like `set terminal aquaterm size 1000,500`. Does fiddling with that setting change the axes in the way you want?

Comment: YES. Thank God... Please post this so I can check it as my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally you want to use the size parameter to the set terminal command to stretch everything out in one direction. For example,

```
set terminal aquaterm size 500,500
```

makes a square plot, and

```
set terminal aquaterm size 1000,500
```

makes a plot that is twice as wide as it is high.